# Extract the columns with the same name out of each dataframe of a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, finance

I have several csv files downloaded from Yahoo finance (each has same number of columns with the same name and same number of rows) in my folder, and I tried to read them into python in one go. I tried with 12 files.
Each file has columns `Date`, `High`, `Low`, `Close`, `Adj Close`, `Volume`.

I searched online, and my code is as follows:

```
csvs = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if x.endswith('.csv')]

fns = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(x))[0] for x in csvs]

d = {}

for i in range(len(fns)):
    d[fns[i]] = pd.read_csv(csvs[i])
print(d)
```

Then I get `d` which consists of 12 dataframes (each has columns `Date` and `Close` and other columns with the same name.
Now I am struggling with how to extract the 'Date' and 'Close' of each dataframes out of the dict `d` and join as a new dataframe (one column as `Date` and 12 columns as the `Close`, the Dates are same), and keep the `Close` column name as the name of the dataframe in `d`?

I tried creating a list like this

```
df_list = [d['AAPL'], d['AMD'], d['BIDU'], d['GOOGL'],d['MSFT'], d['NVDA'], d['NXPI'], d['QCOM'], d['SWKS'], d['TXN'], d['^IXIC'], d['^NDXT']]
```

and then step by step like this

```
aapl = df_list[0]
amd = df_list[1]
bidu = df_list[2]
googl = df_list[3]
msft = df_list[4]
nvda = df_list[5]
nxpi = df_list[6]
qcom = df_list[7]
swks = df_list[8]
txn = df_list[9]
ixic = df_list[10]
ndxt = df_list[11]

mydf = pd.concat([aapl[['Date', 'Close']], amd[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf, bidu[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,googl[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,msft[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,nvda[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,nxpi[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,qcom[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,swks[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,txn[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,ixic[['Close']]], axis = 1)
mydf = pd.concat([mydf,ndxt[['Close']]], axis = 1)
```

And then I got my dataframe with one column as `Date` and 12 columns as `Close`, but the labels of the column are all `Close`.

The dataframe I got is something like this:

| Date | Close | Close | Close | Close | Close | Close | Close | Close | Close | Close | Close | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-06-02 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2011-06-03 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2011-06-04 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2011-06-05 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-05-28 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

There are 2515 rows, and the number 1/2 are just for example.

I am wondering that

1. how can I change the labels of the columns, my expectation is like this (for IXIC and NDXT, the original file name is `^IXIC` and `^NDXT`):

| Date | AAPL | AMD | BIDU | GOOGL | MSFT | NVDA | NXPI | QCOM | SWKS | TXN | IXIC | NDXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-06-02 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2011-06-03 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2011-06-04 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2011-06-05 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-05-28 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

2. How can I make the code easier so that I do not need to write any hard code like 'AAPL' since I have hundreds of files and it would be terrible to create this simple dataframe step by step like what I have done.

I am new to Python and playing with dataframes. Hope I have explained my question clearly, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please give a sample table with your expectation, and sample input. That will help to understand it clearly and provide an answer

Comment: @FelixKJose Thank you for your reply. I have created my df and my expected df, and clarify my question, hope this helps. Could you give some suggestion about changing the code?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a couple of representative lines (w/ headers) from one of the CSV files? Also, where do you get the tickers from?

Comment: I have edited my question, hope this helps explaining my question.

Comment: Simply take the column you want to keep, rename it based on the file name, and then stick it on the accumulating dataframe. Put all of that in a loop. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read these files in one go and unstack them.
A sample code (since I do not have your input files) to sketch the idea...

```py
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

def read_file(f):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df['ticker'] = f.split('.')[0].strip('^')
    return df


df = pd.concat([read_file(f) for f in glob('*.csv')])
df = df.set_index(['Date','ticker'])[['Close']].unstack()
```

Comment: By the way, I think you should use Adj. Close instead of Close because that account for corporation actions while close does not